# Error displayed in adodb recordset in QTP - fetching values from excel

Tags: database, qtp, adodb, recordset

I am executing a record set query with different values pulled from an excel sheet but I am facing an issue:

```
Set objConSql=Createobject("ADODB.connection")
Set objRsSql=Createobject("ADODB.recordset")

Var = Cust_101

objRsSql.Open “Select * from customer where custid = " & Var
```

I want the query to execute as `Select * from customer where custid =101` but the value `Cust_101` want to pass from excel sheet cell.

Comment: you described what you want to achieve and what you tried, can you add a bit more information what is not working, error messages or the like?

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for the response. I am facing error like Cust_101 is not valid table name

Comment: Hi can we have update on this ?? any one??

Comment: Please add the info what error occurs when to the question. You currently say your get error *like* "Cust_101 is not valid table name". So what EXACTLY are you getting WHEN?

Comment: Its solved the answer is objRsSql.Open “Select * from customer where custid = " & "Var"